# Accents and special characters in MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have got a problem with accents and special characters such as: ñ, ç...

I use the following code to introduce data on a MySQL DB:

```
$artist = mb_convert_encoding(mb_convert_case($_POST["artist"], MB_CASE_TITLE), "UTF-8");
$title = mb_convert_encoding(mb_convert_case($_POST["title"], MB_CASE_TITLE), "UTF-8");
$name = mb_convert_encoding(mb_convert_case($_POST["name"], MB_CASE_TITLE), "UTF-8");

$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO songs (artist, title, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$query->execute(array($artist, $title, $name));
```

An example that fails (artist of the song / title of the song / ádam gracia). This is inserted as:

```
Artist Of The Song / Title Of The Song / Ãdam Gracia)
```

The worst of it is that locally (localhost), works perfectly, on my hosting, it gives the above output. The same happens with ç, ñ, etc..

I have tried changing encoding options at php my admin, but I don´t know what to do...

Thank you all!

Comment: @aris, changing the sql database charset, it was in latin ci, now it is in utf8_spanish_ci. Same problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to set the charset in the connection like :

```
new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName;charset=utf-8", $dbUser, $dbPass);
```

Comment: Ok, im stupid enough and I just saw that the connection file for the hosting does NOT contain this last bit (charset=utf-8)... Sorry for the problems jeje.